# Truncate Equivalent command for Azure DocumentDB

Tags: azure-cosmosdb

I have a collection with over 1000 json documents. I want to now delete all the documents in that collection.

Is there any way of doing it from the portal using a query?

PS: I know I can delete the collection and re-create it or use a c# application to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there is no equivalent to the SQL DELETE expression in DocumentDB so there is no way to do it with a query. Here is a stored procedure (CoffeeScript) that does this for me when I want to delete based upon a query.

```
deleteSomeDocuments = (memo) ->

  collection = getContext().getCollection()

  unless memo?
    memo = {}
  if memo.returnDeleted
    unless memo.deleted?
      memo.deleted = []
  else
    memo.returnDeleted = false

  stillQueuingOperations = true

  query = () ->
    if stillQueuingOperations
      responseOptions =
        pageSize: memo.remaining
      setBody()
      if memo.filterQuery?
        memo.stillQueueing = collection.queryDocuments(collection.getSelfLink(), memo.filterQuery, responseOptions, onReadDocuments)
      else
        memo.stillQueueing = collection.readDocuments(collection.getSelfLink(), responseOptions, onReadDocuments)

  onReadDocuments = (err, resources, options) ->
    if err
      throw err

    if resources.length isnt memo.remaining
      throw new Error("Expected memo.remaining (#{memo.remaining}) and the number of rows returned (#{resources.length}) to match. They don't.")

    memo.stillQueueing = true
    while memo.remaining > 0 and memo.stillQueueing
      oldDocument = resources[memo.remaining - 1]
      documentLink = oldDocument._self
      etag = oldDocument._etag
      options = {etag}  # Sending the etag per best practice, but not handling it if there is conflict.
      getContext().getResponse().setBody(memo)
      memo.stillQueueing = collection.deleteDocument(documentLink, options)
      if memo.stillQueueing
        if memo.returnDeleted
          memo.deleted.push(oldDocument)
        memo.remaining--

  setBody = () ->
    getContext().getResponse().setBody(memo)

  query()
  return memo

exports.deleteSomeDocuments = deleteSomeDocuments
```

Comment: One more sproc implementation here: https://github.com/aliuy/azure-node-samples/blob/master/documentdb-server-side-js/stored-procedures/bulkDelete.js

Comment: Any idea if it will be added?

Comment: There is a feature request for INSERT, UPDATE, and DELETE. It's marked as "Under Review". http://feedback.azure.com/forums/263030-documentdb/suggestions/6346033-set-based-operations-insert-update-delete , however, I personally think that with the introduction of JavaScript native query syntax, that they are moving away from being more SQL-like. That's fine with me as long as they upgrade the JavaScript native to support sending in strings for filter function definitions.